# Maintain consistant state between containers

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working with React/Redux app. In my app, I have an 'AllRestaurants' container iterates through an array of JSON objects and creates a list of restaurants.

I'm then using React-Router to link to allow clicking onto a restaurant's name from that list and rendering a 'Restaurant' container that will feature that specific restaurant and all of it's details.

Once a restaurant's name is clicked and the 'AllRestaurants' list container is replaced on the page for a 'Restaurant' container, I do have 'restaurants' and 'selectedRestaurant' available in my state; however, when I'm on the page with the 'Restaurant' container already loaded and hit refresh, my selectedRestaurant in my state is null (because that's the default state).

How can I have this set up so that my state is already aware of my selected restaurant and is set if the 'Restaurant' container is already loaded?

Thank you!

**AllRestaurants.js (container)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { selectRestaurant } from '../../actions/restaurantActions';

class AllRestaurants extends Component {
  renderRestaurants() {
    const allRestaurants = this.props.restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={restaurant.name}
          onClick={() => this.props.selectRestaurant(restaurant)}
        >
          <Link to={`/restaurants/${restaurant.linkName}`}>
            <h1>{restaurant.name}</h1>
          </Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
    return allRestaurants;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.renderRestaurants()}</ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    restaurants: state.restaurants,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    selectRestaurant: selectRestaurant,
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllRestaurants);
```

**index.js (reducer)**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import allRestaurantsReducer from './allRestaurantsReducer';
import selectedRestaurantReducer from './selectedRestaurantReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  restaurants: allRestaurantsReducer,
  selectedRestaurant: selectedRestaurantReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**restaurantActions.js (action)**

```
const SELECT_RESTAURANT = 'SELECT_RESTAURANT';

export function selectRestaurant(restaurant) {
  return {
    type: SELECT_RESTAURANT,
    payload: restaurant,
  }
}
```

**SelectRestaurantReducer.js (reducer)**

```
const SELECT_RESTAURANT = 'SELECT_RESTAURANT';

export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SELECT_RESTAURANT:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: By "refresh the page" you mean a browser refresh, correct?

Comment: Yes, a browser refresh.

Comment: I'm curious on the best practice here as well, but I believe you need to hydrate the initial state from the server side, per [Redux Store docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html).  So if you hit refresh on the browser, it requests for example `/restaurants/some-restaurant` from the server, and the server loads that json from the DB and puts it into the store in the same format as it would have from the client side had you navigated from `/restaurants`. It would be nice if React/Redux could automatically handle loading the state from the parent container/component (restaurants list).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that check the state of restaurants and its null then call the actions that will fetch the data from server and restore the state.

For example:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.restaurant.length==0){
      this.props.youractions.call_the_actions()
    }
  }
```